# (Notepad++) HTML Preview not available

Tags: html, class, notepad++

I'm working on a project for class and I need to use HTML preview to see my work so far. Whenever I try it, I get a blank window saying preview not available.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Identity Theft</title>
</head>
<body style=background-color:lightsteelblue>
    <h1 style=text-align:center;color:blue> Protecting against identity theft</h1>
    <hr style=background-color:white size=5px>
    <div style="font-family;Arial">
        <h2> Keping Your Personal Information Secure Online</h2>
        <ol><li> Be aklert to impersonators</li></ol>
        <li> Safely dispose of personal information</li>
        <li>encrypt your data</li>
        <li> Keep passwords private</li>
        <li> Don't overshare on social networking sites</li>
    <h2> Keeping your devices secure</h2>
    <ul><li> Use Security Software</li>
    <li>lock up your laptop</li>
    <li>Be Wise about wi-fi</li>
    <li> Avoid phishing emails</li>
    <li> Read privacy policies</li></ul>
</div>
<p>Source:<a href="https:www.consumer.ftc.gov/article/0722-how-keep-your-personal-information-secure#online"> Federal Trade Commission</a></p>
    <div align ="center">
        <h3> Report Crimes or Suspicious Activity</h3>
        <table  border ="2">
        <tr>
            <th>Activity</th> 
            <th>Contact</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Identity Theft</td>
            <td><a href="https://www.identitytheft.gov/"> The Federal Trade Commission </a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> Internet Crime </td>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can always save the file and open the file in a browser.

Comment: First off, it looks like you are missing quotes around your style attribute values. style="style: stuff"

Comment: @Dan Farrel. All it does is open a window with the code

Comment: Works for me. How do you run it? Type Ctrl + Alt + shift + X if you want to open in firefox.

Comment: @ toto I save it exit out and try to right-click open with chrome. I'll try what you do.

Comment: @toto also did you try it with,my code. I'm aware i have to fix some quotation marks in there

Comment: When you are **in** Notepad++, save the file DO NOT EXIT and type the characters I gave above or Ctrl + Alt + Shift + R for Chrome.

Comment: @ toto ok so when you did Ctrl+Alt+X I'm assuming you,tried it with the code I,put up right?

Comment: Ctrl + Alt + Shift + X is working for me with Notepad++ Version 7.5 8 using your code.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask.

Answer (score 1):

View your HTML file rendered dynamically as you type.

1. From **Plugins** > **Plugin Manager**, install plugin **Preview HTML**.
2. Focus your HTML File.
3. Select **Plugins** > **Preview HTML** > **Preview HTML**.
4. The window now should show HTML file (if not, test it on a simple sample). Keep the window floating or dock it, e.g. to the bottom of the Notepad++ window.
5. Type at least one character into your HTML code to see the preview.

Comment: Just for the record, this plugin is limited to the Internet Explorer engine only, which is heavily outdated and lacks support for new HTML, CSS, and JavaScript features. Be careful if you intend to use it to test real websites.